# SVN Error after Merge and Commit

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

I merged a branch to another branch and then made some of my own changes. When I went to check in the changes, I got this error:

Error:
- C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0
In directory 
C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0\Unit Tests\MessageProcessor.Tests'
Error processing command 'committed' in 
'C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0\Unit Tests\MessageProcessor.Tests'
Can't move 
C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0\Unit Tests\MessageProcessor.Tests.svn\dir-props' to 
C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0\Unit Tests\MessageProcessor.Tests.svn\dir-prop-base': The system cannot find the file specified.

Now I cannot commit (get "working copy locked, please execute cleanup" message), and executing "cleanup" gives the same message as above.

When I remove the offending directory as [Greg Hewgill](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1381457/svn-error-after-merge-and-commit/1381487#1381487) suggested and do an update, update asks for cleanup, and cleanup throws an error on a different subdirectory.

I'm going to check out a new copy of the source and manually merge my changes in, but I was wondering if A) there's a better way to fix this and B) if anyone knows what I did wrong.

Using TortoiseSVN 1.6.3, Build 16613 and Subversion 1.6.3 on Windows XP.

Comment: There is something fishy about the error message: there are \ characters missing: "\MessageProcessor.Tests.svn\dir-props" should actually be "\MessageProcessor.Tests\.svn\dir-props"

Comment: @wcoenen You're right, but that's just a copy/paste thing. I'll fix it.

Comment: Actually, the slashes are there when I go to edit it, but they don't appear in the preview pane. Weird.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think you did anything wrong, this happens sometimes with TortoiseSVN. Sometimes this is related to:

- virus checker activity. Turn off virus checkers for your source directories if possible.
- renames of files or directories that *only* change the case of the file (ie. tests -> Tests).

When this happens I usually try to fix it by removing or renaming the offending directory (in your case, `C:\dev\Backend\Backend_1.1.0.0\Unit Tests\MessageProcessor.Tests`) and then doing an Update to recreate that directory. Make sure that you don't accidentally throw away stuff that hasn't been committed yet.

Comment: Good points. I did try turning off the virus checker (Norton), that had no effect. None of the files had been renamed at all, let alone case. I tried removing the directory and updating, but tried to update asks for cleanup, and cleanup throws the same error for other directories. I'll add that information to the question.

Comment: This fixed the problem for me. I removed (well moved out of the way)  all troublesome subdirectories, then did svn update and svn cleanup on the higher level directory. Everything's back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Download another copy and check if that one is correct. Sometimes this happens when the .svn files corrupts (for some akward reason but happens). I it is, keep the new and there you go. If not, make the changes, and commit again.

Comment: That's what I've done, and the new copy is correct. I'm just trying to figure out how to avoid this in the future, as manually merging my differences is a pain.